# How to implement an Objective-C in Swift without defining a new class

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, interface, protocols

In Java we can declare an interface and then create a new object which conforms to that interface very simply.

```
public interface Executer {

    void execute();
}

Executer executer = new Executer() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {

        System.out.println("we did it!");
    }
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing, by defining a protocol in Objective-C and implementing it in Swift.

```
@protocol Executer <NSObject>
- (void)execute;
@end
```

How do I implement this protocol in my Swift code like in the Java example?

Comment: could you please elaborate your requirement??

If you want to use your ObjC protocol in Swift then first you need to add a Bridge Header class so that you can access ObjC code in swift.
The purpose of protocols are same in both the languages.

If you want to define it similarly as the Java code you have written then i will suggest you to write your protocol in Swift as they are powerful in swift than in ObjC.
And then extend them with Protocol Extension feature.

Comment: @Deepak I want to instantiate the Executor class in Swift by just overriding/implementing the execute method. I know about the Bridging Header, that is all fine.

Comment: you cannot extend ObjC protocols like Swift Protocol Extension feature.

But you can use ObjC protocol like this:- 

class Test: NSObject, Executer {
    func execute() {
        print("tested")
    }
}

Comment: @Deepak thanks for this. I want to do it without explicitly defining a new class though, like we can in Java. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If your protocol would be in swift the Protocol Extension is your answer but there is no way you can do this with ObjC protocols.

Comment: @Deepak - How would protocol extension be the solution? Surely you still need a type (struct or class) which implements the protocol as you cannot instantiate a protocol by itself, even one with a default implementation of a method.

Comment: @CRD yes you are absolutely right. I just gave the answer as the question code asked i.e. unlike 'Interface' ObjC protocols cannot work. However Swift Protocol Extensions can give you a global solution for some tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift does not have a direct equivalent of Java's anonymous classes.

You don't say *why* you want to do this, e.g. what is it about this construct that makes you want it over what Swift does provide? Given that we'll just show two alternatives, maybe one will suit you.

Swift supports nested types, so you can declare a local type within your class and instantiate it. For example:

```
@objc public class Explore : NSObject
{
    @objc private class notAnAnonButPrivateClass : NSObject, Executer
    {
        func execute() -> Void
        {
            print("we did it!")
        }
    }

    var executer : Executer = notAnAnonButPrivateClass()
```

This declares the private class and then an instance variable initialised to an instantiation of it.

If you want to be able to provide the implementation of `execute()` inline with the declaration then you can do that using a Swift *closure* (equivalent to *block* in Objective-C) and use the *trailing closure* syntax to pretty it up a bit:

```
@objc private class notAnAnonButPrivateClass : NSObject, Executer
{
    let executeImpl : () -> Void

    init(_ theImpl : @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        executeImpl = theImpl
    }

    func execute() -> Void
    {
        executeImpl()
    }
}

var executer : Executer = notAnAnonButPrivateClass() {
    print("we did it again!")
}
```

In this version the private class' `init` takes a closure to use for the body of `execute()` and that closure is written directly in line in the instance variable initialisation.

This version also differs semantically from the first as the closure may capture values and variables from its enclosing scope.

So to summarise: you don't get anon classes, you must give them a name (but can use something more sensible than `notAnAnonButPrivateClass`!) and that name does not "leak" into the rest of your code (the `private` bit); and you can if you (really) wish provide the method body at the point of instantiation. Maybe one of these will suit you.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need. I use this construction in Java where I have, in class `A`, an internal `Executor` variable that I want to be able to set after instantiation. It gets set by an instance of class `B`, and the `Executor` that class `B` creates must have its `execute` method refer to the internal scope of the `B` instance. This is a way of dynamically setting a method from an external context. Now I'm modifying a CocoaPod which is written in Objective-C, and I need to be able to dynamically set a method of an object there from the main body of my app, which is written in Swift.